# Find the probability that the sample will contain five symbols of each kind.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

From the population of five symbols $a, b, c, d, e$, a sample of size $25$ is taken. Find the probability that the sample will contain five symbols of each kind.

My understanding of this question is that a sample of size 25 must contain at least one in each symbol. Thus, the number of such ways is equivalent to finding the number of distinguishable distributions of 25 balls in which no 5 cell remains empty, which is ${24 \choose 4}$. Therefore, the probability is ${24 \choose 4} / 5^{25}$. However, the answer is $25!(5!)^{-5} 5^{-25}$. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of ordered selections of length $25$ from the set of five symbols, with replacement, is $5^{25}$. The number of such selections with five symbols of each kind is a multinomial coefficient $\binom{25}{5,5,5,5,5}=25!/(5!)^5$ – if all the symbols were distinct, there would be $25!$ selections, and we divide by $5!$ to account for the indistinguishability of each symbol. The quotient of the second count over the first gives the correct probability.